# jogl, polygon as own object/class

Tags: draw, jogl, polygons

I want to draw a polygon as an own object in its own class, not as part of the display method. I havn't found that much about it, hope someone here can help me.

```
public PolygonalGameObject(GameObject parent, double points[],
       double[] fillColour, double[] lineColour) {
   super(parent);

   myPoints = points;
   myFillColour = fillColour;
   myLineColour = lineColour;
}

public void drawSelf(GL2 gl) {

// TODO: Write this method

  gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
  gl.glLoadIdentity();

  gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);{
  for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i += 2) {
      double x = myPoints[i];   
      double y = myPoints[i + 1];
      gl.glVertex2d(x, y);
  }
  }gl.glEnd();
}
```

A GameObject contains several polygonalGameObjects in a scene graph/tree

I'm pretty new at this (both programming and graphics), so if anybody got some good tutorials please post then!

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a current OpenGL context to draw something with OpenGL and that's why you need to call your drawing methods in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable), the OpenGL context is guaranteed to be current on this thread during a call of this method. It's possible to use JOGL without GLEventListener but it's more dangerous especially if you're a beginner and it's a waste of time because it doesn't give any flexibility whereas it forces you to handle the life cycle of your drawable by yourself. Using a GLEventListener doesn't prevent you from creating your own classes, you just have to call your drawing methods directly or indirectly in display().

If you have any questions about JOGL, rather ask them on [the official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/). You can look at [the wiki](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) too. You need to learn plain OpenGL to use JOGL, you can read the OpenGL Red Book. If you're very new at programming, I don't think you should start with graphics, you should start with something a lot more simple first in order to learn the basic principles of Java programming before learning 2D and the principles of 3D computer graphics.